# What is the intended purpose of `sudo_as` from the sudo pallet?

Tags: pallet, transactions, account, key, sudo

I ask myself, why this extrinsic (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/e9b0facf70eeb08032cc7e83548c62f0b4a24bb1/frame/sudo/src/lib.rs#L224-L263) exists? I mean the sudo key could execute any transaction from any account, although the sudo user might not have the private key of this account.

When I would like to stop this dispatch from being executed, I could use the transaction filter, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes `Sudo::sudo_as` can be used to impersonate any other account of type `Signed` whereas `Sudo::sudo` provides `Root`.

> When I would like to stop this dispatch from being executed, I could use the transaction filter, right?

No. You cannot rely on such simple assumptions about how pallets interact. It gives of a false sense of security while (in most cases) not even archieving what you want. Once someone acquires Root, through Sudo or other, they can do *anything*.

In your case it would indeed hinder direct dispatches to `Sudo::sudo_as`, but `Root` (acquired through `Sudo::sudo`) has many ways to hack around that. The obvious like `Utility::dispatch_as` and the more mischievous being `System::set_code`.

Comment: Is there any existing pallet, which has less power than the sudo pallet, but without token holder votes like in the democracy pallet. So I am searching for a pallet, which has a privileged account, that can do runtime upgrades, but only after a long review period these upgrades get enacted.